# Messages - Is there a way to implement an "archive" feature?

Tags: iphone, imac, messages

For those of us for whom text messages often represent an undone or unorganized task, it would be helpful to have an archive feature in Messages apps. That way, we could see which messages have not yet been responded to or dealt with.

As it is, it's very easy to forget to respond.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

Neither is this functionality built into the Messages app, nor is it possible to enable it by any means.

Comment: To channel Charles Dickens by using his famous idiom, ["never say never"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/never+say+never). :)

Comment: Not answer as it isn't an archive and Messages doesn't have a Share icon that would make it more seamless, but it didn't take too long to build a Workflow that took whatever was in the clipboard and created a reminder with a a title of "Reminder from Messages" with the text of the reminder from the clipboard.